# Determining the computational time needed to solve a homogeneous system of quadratic equations

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

I'm trying to solve a system of quadratic equations with `Solve`.

If I have 48 quadratic equations for 15 variables the code works perfectly fine.

If instead I have 57 quadratic equations for 15 variables the code just keeps running.

I was wondering if anybody knows a formula or way to calculate the time Mathematica will need to solve such a non-linear system. I would like to know this to determine whether the problem is in my code or if it's just a long computation issue.

#### Edit

I know for sure that my system has nontrivial solutions.

Comment: This is a hard question to answer, since in general a system of $48$ quadratic equations in $15 variables should only have the trivial solution ($\mathbf{0}$), so your system must have special structure, which will certain affect the running time. Perhaps if you posted your equations and your code, more enlightenment would be had.

Comment: @IgorRivin I'm basically solving some Jacobi identities for a thing called "Lie bialgebra", so It's all well grounded problem, theoretically. If the system had no solutions some Groups that we know exist wouldn't. My concerns are about the Solve algorithm.. I know it works fine for linear systems but what about quadratic ones?

Comment: Yes, I believe you, but what I am saying is that your system is not a *general* system of quadratic equations, so no general statement applies to it. If you post your problem, you might get a sensible answer.

Comment: This question will be easier to answer and more useful for others if you add a minimal working example of working code and data to show specifically what you are working with. Please [edit] your question to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Include a minimum example of code that shows the problem and an example of the desired output.